# Parse Database PDF Export

Tags: database, parse-platform, xamarin

I was wondering if there is any way to export data from the Parse.com database (based on conditions) to a PDF format. There does not seem to be any built-in functionality for this but I may be missing something.

The purpose of this is to create a monthly report of new entries into the database.

The only solution I can find is to pull out ParseObjects using a query against a condition (in this case, creation date) and then having to manually extract fields and construct a PDF document using a third-party library.

Although I cannot find any solutions, I feel that this sort of functionality would be commonly required and perhaps I am missing something.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function, you could try to use a JavaScript library in a Cloud Code Background Job to write the file and schedule the job to run once a month, or like you already said, query the data using the API and write the file on your own server/client. That's pretty much your only option at the moment.

Comment: Fanastic! Thank you for your response. I'll look into that :)